# Issues with twin.macro in a monorepo where Storybook is at the root

Tags: tailwind-css, storybook, monorepo, tailwind-in-js

I'm trying to use twin.macro in a component library. It's a monorepo setup with Storybook at the root. I seem to be having issues accessing tailwind.config.js. Inside each of the packages I've got babel-plugin-macros.config.js. When the config is like this, Storybook doesn't pick up my custom colors. But I'm able to build the packages just fine with `npm run build`.

```
module.exports = {
    twin: {
      config: '../../tailwind.config.js',
      preset: "emotion",
    },
  };
```

Minimal repro on GitHub: https://github.com/ashleynexvelsolutions/twin-macro-monorepo-with-storybook-broken

When the config file is like this, Storybook runs just fine. However, when I run `npm run build`, Rollup doesn't pick up the custom colors.

```
module.exports = {
  twin: {
    config: 'tailwind.config.js',
    preset: "emotion",
  },
};
```

Minimal repro on GitHub: https://github.com/ashleynexvelsolutions/twin-macro-monorepo-with-rollup-broken

In each scenario, I'm getting the same error.

```
MacroError: (path)/twin-macro-monorepo-with-storybook-broken/packages/Button/Button.js: 

✕ text-test-one was not found

Try one of these classes:
```

Then it proceeds to list Tailwind defaults, like text-white, text-gray-300, etc.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I am not sure what's causing this error and how it can be fixed

Comment: @JoeNg'ethe Unfortunately I haven't had any luck getting it sorted out either. I opened up a discussion on twin.macro's GitHub, which can be found here: https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/discussions/657 If you wouldn't mind jumping over there & tagging the same guy I tagged, hopefully we can maybe get it sorted out.